# Why does java give different result for guitar chords

Tags: java, regex

First, I try to extract all guitar chords from a simple text file using a regular expression. To me, it is working on https://regexr.com/ but it isn't working properly in java.

In this (simplified) task, a chord

- should start with an upper case letter (CDEFGAB) (it is required always)
- it can be followed by # or b (just one of them)
- it also could be followed by m, 7, or m7 (just one of them)
- if there is # or b then it precedes m, 7, or m7
- the chord shouldn't be bounded by a word character (i.e. "\nA#7 " would be a good example)

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 IDE. I tried the following code snippet:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {     
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[CDEFGAB](([#b](?=\\s))|([#b]m7\\b)|([#b][m7]\\b)|(m7\\b)|([m7]\\b)|(\\b))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        while (m.find()) {
            chords.add(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

I get most chords but not the ones end with # and stand at the end of a line. I.e. I get only "F" (instead of "F#") here:

`"C#                        F#\n"`

It could be a good text for it:
https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/george_benson/nothings_gonna_change_my_love_for_you_chords_1080047

Comment: It can be that new lines `\n` are translated into new line and carriage return (`\n\r`), so single `\s` doesn't match that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sharp expression is looking to match a space after it. The last chord in a line isn't matching that. You can either add a space to the line.

```
  Matcher m = p.matcher(line + " ");
```

or add an extra condition to your regular expression `([#b]$)` and make sure the $ is set to match a new line vs the end of string using `Pattern.MULTILINE`.

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[CDEFGAB](([#b]$)|([#b](?=\\s))|([#b]m7\\b)|([#b][m7]\\b)|(m7\\b)|([m7]\\b)|(\\b))", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess it will be the problem. So (if I understand you) when I read the file it removes the newline character at the end of a line and it causes the problem. Still I have to get some parts of the comment but the main problem was this one (I guess).

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a *much* simpler regex:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b[A-G][b#]?m?7?(?!\\w)")
```

This should do exactly what you need. You can even expand it (Guitars have major and diminished 7th chords too, right?)

```
Pattern.compile("\\b[A-G][b#]?(7|m7?|M7|dim7?)?(?!\\w)")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that one but somehow it doesn't recognise patterns like G#, F#, etc.. Yet I didn't understand exactly why.

Comment: Thank you, this way it really works. I still don't understand exactly why it works only with positive lookahead (bot doesn't with \b at the end).

Comment: @DoWhileFor it's because the word boundary `\b` won't match between the sharp character `#` and a space, because neither of them are word characters. But it will match after a `7` or a `b`.

Comment: thanks. Somehow I considered C#, F#, etc. a whole unit (though it is really logical that # is not a word character). I don't know why.